# How can i use fields in query/aggregate as reference instead of hardcoded strings in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i want to reference mongoDB fields in queries and aggregates instead of using fields as hardcoded strings.
For example:
This what i'm doing now:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

const CatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', CatSchema);

Cat.findOne({name: 'beauty'}).exec()  //using name field hardcoded in code
//OR
Cat.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            name: 'beauty' //using name field hardcoded in code
        }
    }
]).exec()
```

What i'm trying to do is something like this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

const CatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

const Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', CatSchema);

Cat.findOne({CatSchema.name: 'beauty'}).exec()  //use a reference as field name
//OR
Cat.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            CatSchema.name: 'beauty' //use a reference as field name
        }
    }
]).exec()
```

Why this? to prevent issues on code on field name changes. And to only do a (right-click + refactor) on the schema field name.

Comment: no, you can't give a reference because it only accepts the key name as a string.